# Unity 2D jump bigger when pressing 2 buttons simultaneously

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this code for my character to jump when it is grounded:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown("w") || Input.GetKeyDown("up") || Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
     {
         GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0f, jumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);            
     }
```

I check if he is grounded with the following code (just like the platformer in Unity's 5 "Standard Assets Example Project").

```
 Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(m_GroundCheck.position, k_GroundedRadius, m_WhatIsGround);
```

The problem is that if I press more than one of the 3 buttons (w , up, space) simultaneously it makes the jump very much higher than it should. (It's almost like giving it double force) So how could I do fix this?

Comment: http://www.quickmeme.com/img/b1/b16846514f96315a2db0501afb434fb5662b92679ee85364c51a3808e7389806.jpg

Comment: I think you're going to have to check for whether or not they are currently on the ground.  If they are already jumping, then just return out.  Otherwise, you could add a flag that you can only jump once a second maybe?   Maybe someone else has a better answer.

Comment: I don't get the problem when I am mid air. I only get it when I press more than one button simultaneously while am still grounded. (haha nice meme btw :P )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you may have found a little glitch. As you know by the documentation, the getkeydown is reset and unless you pressed it again, the result will be false, however in the jump, it only consumes the first getkeydown, by the time you get the next update, even though you added the force, it may still be on the ground, thus processing the other getkeydown. As an experience try the following:

```
bool jump = false;
if(Input.GetKeyDown("w"))
  jump = true;
if(Input.GetKeyDown("up"))
  jump = true;
if(Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
  jump = true;
if (jump)
 {
     GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0f, jumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);            
 }
```

Comment: Ok so I did some tests with this code.When I have both the input part and the actual jumpforce in the Update, I still have the same problem. Now If I have both in FixedUpdate, it kinda works because I don't get the bigger jump, But sometimes some of the keypress doesn't work and character won't jump. So lastly I tried to put input on Update  (so that I don't miss any keypress) and the jump force in FxedUpdate so that physics apply better, but I still get the bigger jump.

Comment: if( input && ! jump) in each of the if clauses

Comment: the getkeydown only works properly in Update, thats why FixedUpdate "eats" some of your input. i would suggest you add a check to see if there is already a force added on the object when you jump.

Comment: yes but you can have it like that only for the ground jump, for example, if(onGround && noForce) jump!